# error near unexpected token 'then' in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting and this is my shell script. I am getting this error and stuck in it

```
 defoul="http://distfiles.gentoo.org/snapshots"
 echo "cheking for latest snapshot">&2
 mkdir -p ~\cashe
 mkdir -p ~\cashe\temp
 cd ~\cashe\
 if [ -e portage-latest.tar.xz.gpgsig ]; then
    mv portage-latest.tar.xz.gpgsig ~\cashe\temp
 fi
```

Comment: You should first replace your \ with / as directory separator. Also if this is a bash script it should normally have `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.

Comment: Unix-like systems do not use the backslash character to separate directory paths. Use `/` instead. (Windows permits both; Unix does not.)

Comment: thanks, I will replace the \, and I have the #!/bin/bash I just omitted it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your paths do not mean what you probably think they mean. `mkdir -p ~\cashe` creates a directory named `~cashe` in the current dir, and `mkdir -p ~\cashe\temp` creates another named `~cashetemp`. At least that's what my bash did. You probably want to use / instead of \.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the 'if' statement with double square brackets, and also include a space between your rightmost square bracket that the ";", so:

if [[ -e ... ]] ; then

It's been my experience that in shell programming, spaces are your friend.  I would make sure to put a space between any two adjoining syntactic elements, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: The question is explicitly tagged "bash"